# How can I tell my (MSTest) test list to run in one of two modes from the command line?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mstest

I have certain tests that are basically run in two modes. One mode runs against minimal data, these are intended to be run after every commit. The other mode runs against extensive data, these are intended to be run nightly.

Right now, I'm using the vsmdi file to split my tests into different lists named per commit and nightly, and my build server calls them through the command line using the vsmdi file and the test list name. For this to work, I have to make two different [TestMethod] functions, one for the per commit mode and one for the nightly mode. Then I of course assign them to one of the two lists.

I thought this was a little tedious.. I know you're not allowed to pass parameters into your test methods, but is there a way to configure the test class so that each test understands what mode it's trying to run in? This configuration needs to be passed through the command line somehow so the build server works, and it would be nice if I could also configure visual studio to be in one mode or the other, or both, at any given point so the test running keyboard shortcuts work right.

Comment: +1, good question. How do you data bind your test? Are you using a database or scv files?

Comment: The applicable tests query a test database by calling my 'business layer' library. I've had my tester serializing the inputs and outputs that he deems to be correct, afterwards tossing them all into a folder in the test project. Then, I use the serialized input objects to generate a test output objects. Then I deserialize the stored output objects and compare it to their corresponding test output object.

Comment: @IBC I'm sorry but I did not understand correctly what is the source of your data. Are you filling test database with data before you run your tests and then use these as test data to your tests or your are using files on some other format as input?

Comment: I'm using a test database and files at the same time.

Comment: Ok, I believe that somehow you define your datasource at each testmethod (maybe using the [DataSource] attribute). Even if you manage to pass a parameter through mstest to your tests, then you need to change the datasource at runtime according to this parameter. I don't know how much easy this is since attributes values are defined on compile time.

Comment: Well, if I come up with something I'll be sure to post the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can acheive this by using MsTest Category Attribute on your unit tests.

```
[Category("Foo")]
[TestMethod]
public void MyTest() {
    // test
}
```

You can place more than one category on each test, so you can mix and match.  Then from the command line you can run the tests with the `/category` switch and again choose which tests to run. Check out [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182487.aspx).

Comment: Oh that's nifty. Can I see in the code what category or categories the test is at run time?

Comment: `Category` should be `TestCategory`, at least for Visual Studio 2015 with which I tried this

Answer (score 1):

If your "extensive" dataset is taking too long to run, then you probably have a problem with your dataset. You should be able to cover all of your test cases in a minimal set of data that runs quickly. Here's my anecdote: I once wrote something to generate USPS barcodes. The USPS very kindly provided 10,000 test cases and their expected results. I dutifully turned these 10,000 test cases into individual unit tests. However, I quickly realized that those 10,000 test cases were largely redundant, and there were really only a couple of dozen *actual* test cases -- the rest were noise. That's what I suspect is going on in your case. You're testing with a large dataset what could be tested with a much smaller one.

Unless, of course, the test case is how your application behaves when processing a large dataset. In that case, split your tests into two assemblies, and configure your build to only run the "quick" test assembly on every checkin, and your nightly build to run both.

Comment: In my case, each test case takes several seconds. I can foresee my nightly tests running for an hour each night.. easily.

Comment: My 'per commit' test coverage will be very niggardly, indeed.